# I cannot open certain attachments because of protection.outlook.com

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook

I cannot open certain attachments in my email because `https//nam.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/? …….`.pops up on the screen. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Safelinks is a system for scanning links, by replacing the link with a link to a service that scans the destination, and then redirects you to it if it is "safe". Safelinks is generally implemented on corporate email platforms, by the administrators. you can request exceptions to safelinks based on patterns like sender, content, etc, but only if your organization allows them. I had to get an exemption on some password reset emails a few weeks ago, because the link can only be used once, and when safelinks scanned it, it used up that one access.

Answer (score 0):

Your outlook is preventing you from opening what it has determined is a bad attachment. If you have an email administrator, you can ask them to release the attachment. But I would ensure that it is safe, first.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb3af262-dd0b-4bd1-9353-0efd3c0f6898/turn-off-advanced-threat-protection-in-outlookcom?forum=outlook

Found a similar issue as you. According to the mentioned official article, we can turn them off by signing in to https://outlook.live.com. Then select Settings > Premium > Security. There's a toggle under Advanced Security that you can use to turn off Safelinks.